# python ftplib open file and check if password fits

Tags: python, readline, ftplib

Im new to python and currently struggeling with following:

I need to merge that:

```
for line in open(dictionaryFile, "r").readlines():
    [username, password] = line.strip().split()
```

Into that code:

```
 import ftplib 

 def anonLogin(hostname):
  try:
    ftp = ftplib.FTP(hostname)
    ftp.login('anonymous', '')
    print('\n[*] ' + str(hostname) +\
      ' FTP Anonymous Logon Succeeded.')
    ftp.quit()
    return True
  except:
    print('\n[-] ' + str(hostname) +\
    ' FTP Anonymous Logon Failed.')
    return False
host = '127.0.0.1'
anonLogin(host)
```

The script should go thorugh a file with username / password combinations and check if logon was successfull or not.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain where did you save something in the file and when do you check the file ?

Comment: You want to read the file line by line and check can you login in the system by username and password from current line, is it ?

Comment: yes thats it. Excactly! The file is sotred in the same directory as the script and within the file there are usernames + passwords in the following format (line by line) - user password

Answer (score 0):

This is a main idea. You need a loop to reed all lines in the file (don't forget close it) and try to connect to server with current pair of login and password. If connection is established login and password will print in console.

```py
import ftplib


def anonLogin(hostname, username, password):
    try:
        ftp = ftplib.FTP(hostname)
        ftp.login(username, password)
        print(f'\n[*] {hostname} FTP Anonymous Logon Succeeded.')
        ftp.quit()
        return True
    except Exception:
        print(f'\n[-] {hostname} FTP Anonymous Logon Failed.')
        return False


host = '127.0.0.1'
dictionaryFile = 'file_path'

f = open(dictionaryFile, 'r')

for line in f.readlines():
    [username, password] = line.strip().split()
    connection = anonLogin(host, username, password)
    if connection:
        print(f'\n {username} {password}')

f.close()
```

Comment: That defo helps! Thank you!!